# Is my method of threading efficient?

Tags: python, sockets, gevent

Basically I just want to know if I implemented threading correctly for concurrent socket threading. Here's my approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
from gevent import socket, Timeout, select
from gevent.pool import Pool

def worker(website):
    data = str()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setblocking(0)
    s.connect(('google.com',80))
    s.send('HEAD / HTTP/1.1\n\n')

    while True:
        read, w, e = select.select([s], [], [])
        if read:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if data:
                break

    print ('done')
    return 0

def main():

    pool = Pool(10)
    for item in items:
            pool.spawn(worker, item)
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Instead of checking `if read:`, I think it might be better (and more readable) to explicitly check for the socket in the read list: `if s in read:`. Also, for something simple like this, why not keep the socket blocking, and just call `read` on it?

Comment: Am I wrong, or does it seem excessive to use a select call on every single greenlet socket? Wouldn't you either create all your sockets and select on the entire set...or if using the pool approach...use the `gevent.socket.wait_read(fileno, ...)` on each individual socket? Or like @JoachimPileborg suggested, just set the socket to block, and directly call recv on each socket?

Comment: If you are only reading one socket, I don't see any reason to use `select`. Heck, even if you're reading from multiple sockets, there's *still* no reason to use select — just spawn multiple green threads to do the reading, then have them write to a queue, or use `Group.map` to stick them in a list, or whatever else makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The threading portion (`pool.spawn`) is fine (although [`Group.map`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html#gevent.pool.Group.map) (or `imap`, or `imap_unordered` might be even prettier).

The `select` is entirely unnecessary, though. Since you're using `gevent`'s patched socket, you can just use:

```
data = s.recv(1024)
```

A few other things:

- You won't need the call to `setblocking` if you're doing it that way.
- To be entirely correct, you should use [`socket.sendall`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall).
- With `gevent`, you will almost never `select`. If you need to read from ten sockets, just spawn ten green threads. For example: results = `Group().map(lambda s: s.read(), my_sockets)`.
- While we're here: it's very strange to use `data = str()` — `data = ""` would be much more standard.